# Brachiograph and Turtle

Tags: turtle-graphics

I am currently in the process of building a Brachiograph plotter. I am 75 years old and have a minor disability with my hands. I would like to find out if anybody can tell me how I can output Turtle Graphics to a file that can be read by the Brachiograph plotter. I believe that the linedraw.py converts a .svg to a .json file that is read by the Brachiograph. I would like to create some fractal image files and print them with the Brachiograph.
Thank you for any help that you can offer with this project.
Dick Burkhartzmeyer

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you state "I believe that the linedraw.py converts a .svg to a .json file[...]". Looking at the [documentation](https://www.brachiograph.art/how-to/use-linedraw.html) it looks like linedraw.py will convert a bitmap to an svg file **and** a json file.

From the [documentation](https://www.brachiograph.art/how-to/use-linedraw.html):

> The main use you will have for linedraw is to take a bitmap image file
> as input, and save the vectorised version as:
>
> ```
> an SVG file, to check it
>
> a JSON file, to draw with the BrachioGraph.
> ```

The way I would approach this is to create an svg with Turtle and then in your Python script convert that to a png. Then linedraw.py can be used to convert that to your JSON BrachioGraph file. I found a solution to do that in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050156/save-turtle-output-as-jpeg). The answer in that thread is using [Cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/) to convert the SVG to PNG format.